# Definition of Curvature

Tags: calculus, curvature

## Derivation of Definition of Curvature

$$ \phi = tan^{-1}(y')$$

1. Differentiate with respect to s.

$$ \frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac d {ds} (tan^{-1} y')$$

2. Chain rule.

$$ \frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac d {dx} (tan^{-1}y') \frac {dx} {ds}$$

3. Chain rule.

$$ \frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac d {d^2y} (tan^{-1}y') \frac {d^2y} {dx^2} \frac {dx} {ds}$$

**The remaining (unlisted) steps I understand, but I have trouble applying the chain rule the second time.**

Here is my attempt to perform the chain rule the second time:

$$ \frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac d {dx} (tan^{-1}y') \frac {dx} {ds}  \frac {d^2y} {d^2y}$$

$$ \frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac d {d^2y} (tan^{-1}y') \frac {dx} {ds}  \frac {d^2y} {dx}$$

**Where does the additional $\frac 1 {dx}$ come from?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g=\frac{dy}{dx}$ so that $\phi = \tan^{-1}(g)$. We make this substitution to relieve us from the abundance of differentials! Then

$$\frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac {d}{dx}\left[\tan^{-1}(g)\right]\frac{dx}{ds}$$
by the chain rule.
But by the chain rule again, $$\frac {d}{dx}\left[\tan^{-1}(g)\right]=\frac{d}{dg}\left[\tan^{-1}(g)\right]\frac{dg}{dx}.$$
Putting those together,
$$\frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac{d}{dg}\left[\tan^{-1}(g)\right]\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{dx}{ds}.$$
But remember our substitution,  $g=\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$.
So, 
$$\frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac{d}{d(y')}\left[\tan^{-1}(y')\right]\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]\frac{dx}{ds},$$
which can be written as
$$\frac {d \phi} {ds} = \frac{d}{d^2y}\left[\tan^{-1}(y')\right]\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dx}{ds}.$$